# numpy.int64 times int -> numpy.float64

Tags: python, numpy, types

I'm using python3 with numpy version 1.8.2 (same issue with numpy 1.10.4 and python2) and trying to do something very basic: multiplying two integers.

```
import numpy as np
a = 9223372036854775808
type(a)
b = np.int64(0)
type(b)
type(b*a)
```

The output is however:

```
builtins.int
numpy.int64
numpy.float64
```

So the multiplication of two integers returns a float! Is there any reasonable explanation for it?

Note that if I change to

```
a = 9223372036854775807
type(b*a)
```

returns

```
numpy.int64
```

And if I raise it to

```
a = 92233720368547758100
type(b*a)
```

returns (in python3)

```
builtins.int
```

and (in python2)

```
long
```

As I understand there must be some overflow, but why?

Comment: *Is there any reasonable explanation for it?*   Yes, it is value range magnitude handling.

Comment: I see, but I find it strange that the type is correctly casted to long when the integer is increased to 92233720368547758100. So, is "long" the only safe way to go for handling long numbers?

Comment: From the documentation https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#numeric-types-int-float-long-complex , **Long integers have unlimited precision.**  Probably it is an efficiency choice:  floats have limited precision and range, but they are computationally fast.  Unlimited precision longs may be very expensive to perform arithmetic on, so casting is reasonable to explicitly ask for that tradeoff.

Comment: Is this an expected behaviour anyway or should I file a bug?

Comment: I just filed a bug. Follow the discussion here:
https://github.com/numpy/numpy/issues/7409

Comment: Looks like the bug discussion is gaining some traction.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it was resolved by filing a bug.

Answer (score 1):

Actually it is very good observation and question. Here is the quick analogy:

```
import numpy as np

a = 9223372036854775808
```

Note that you are crossing the `int` limit, it is entering the `long int` range

> `a` will produce output as `9223372036854775808L`
>
> `type(a)` will produce output as `<type 'long'>`

In the below case, we are staying with in the `int` limit

```
a = 9223372036854775807
```

> Here `a` returns output as `9223372036854775807`
>
> type(a) returns output as `<type 'int'>`

let us assume `b = np.int64(1)` for instance. I will explain in while why I took `np.int64(1)` instead of `np.int64(0)`

> `b*a` returns `9.2233720368547758e+18`, as you see it is represented in decimals in Euler's form.
>
> `type(b*a)` returns `np.float64`

Hence for the above reason, it is converted to float i.e., np.float(64). Eulers form of number always needs float/decimal points for its representation

Reason for considering `b` as `np.int64(1)`: If it was `np.int64(0)`, you will never notice the output as the result will be all 0s

Answer (score 0):

This answer is not really an answer: is an attempt to try understand the issue better!

With Python 2.7.13 I got

```
In [24]: a = 9223372036854775808; type(a)
Out[24]: long
```

While in python 3.6.0 I got

```
In [24]: a = 9223372036854775808; type(a)
Out[24]: int
```

And this is coherent with the fact that long are still called int even if behaving like long in Python3.

Can this be part of the problem of the reported bug? If we stay on Python2, can what you saw be a bug of numpy in querying the type of a value stored in a variable when performing a multiplication? 
Consider

```
In [11]: type(int(9223372036854775807))
Out[11]: int

In [12]: type(int(9223372036854775808))
Out[12]: long


In [13]: a = 9223372036854775808

In [14]: b = np.int64(0)

In [15]: type(9223372036854775808 * np.int64(0)) 
Out[15]: long

In [16]: type(b*a)
Out[16]: numpy.float64

In [17]: type(long(9223372036854775808) * np.int64(0))
Out[17]: long

In [18]: type(int(9223372036854775808) * np.int64(0))
Out[18]: long

In [19]: type(np.int64(9223372036854775808) * np.int64(0))
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
OverflowError                             Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-18-93a64125698a> in <module>()
----> 1 type(np.int64(9223372036854775808) * np.int64(0))

OverflowError: Python int too large to convert to C long
```

The number 9223372036854775808 is stored as long.

Line 15 the processor says *"long times int64 is long as it is the biggest container".*

Line 16 the processor sees a as int and said *"int times np.int64 is np.int64 as I prefer to store it in a numpy type, since you call it, but wait... 9223372036854775808 cannot stay in int64, so I am in trouble now (unexpected trouble, as it not happen when using only numpy type - line 19). I then put myself in "trouble mode" storing the results by default in the largest numpy container I have, which is float64"*.

In Python3 lines 15 and 16 behaves differently: numpy goes always in "trouble mode" as the long type is always detected as an int:

```
In [10]: type(9223372036854775808 + np.int64(0))
Out[10]: numpy.float64

In [11]: type(a*b)
Out[11]: numpy.float64
```